# Source for CompositeCollection: why can't I bind against the data context of another control but have to use a CollectionViewSource?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, collectionviewsource, compositecollection

In [another question I recently asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25413252/779395), I was told to use a `CompositeCollection` in order to access various sources for a `ListBox`.

The example used a `XmlDataProvider` to provide some dummy data. I, however, have a view model, which contains the data.

It took me some time to bind my `ListBox` against the view model's data. Eventually I figured it out, but now I'd like to understand why my previous approaches didn't work.

The key to success was a CollectionViewSource. My initial attempts were:

```
<CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Movies}"/>
<CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=DataContext.Movies}"/>
```

My idea was to find the Window, which has the appropriate DataContext, and bind against the data. You can do that via `FindAncestor` or via `ElementName`, so I tried both. That seemed very logically to me, but apparently I was wrong. I didn't see nothing when I ran the application.
I also tried binding against another control which has the data context; e.g. the `StackPanel`.

So, why don't I get the data with `FindAncestor` and `ElementName`<sup>1</sup>, but have to provide a `CollectionViewSource` explicitly?

---

Here's the code that is working.

```
<StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <ListBox ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CustomDataTemplateSelector}">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ViewSource" Source="{Binding Movies}"/>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewSource}}"/>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyButtonsData}}"/>
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                   Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth),
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> No, I didn't forget to name the window and there wasn't a typo either.

Comment: With your initial attempt you should have some binding errors in the debug console. They are of great help when debugging this type of issue.

Comment: @Pragmateek Actually, I don't. I only get the hint "cannot resolve property of type object" which is fixed once I add the data context via DesignInstance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a [thread on microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b15cbd9d-95aa-47c6-8068-7ae9f7dca88a/collectioncontainer-does-not-support-relativesource?forum=wpf) discussing that issue.
Seems that this 'bug' is known for years, but has never been fixed.

The workaround I'm using (`CollectionViewSource`) is suggested there, too.

Furthermore, you can indeed not use `ElementName`. I don't know for what reason, but the workaround for `ElementName` is using `x:Reference` as [suggested in another question's thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6446923/779395).

```
<CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={x:Reference dummy}, Path=DataContext.Movies}"/>
```

Interestingly, the XAML compiler will show an `object reference not set to an instance of an object` error while editing.
It's possible to compile and run though, provided you're not using an ancestor type, because than you'll get an XmlParseException because of a circular dependency.

To avoid the circular dependency error, you can put the CompositeCollection in the resources and link to there via StaticResource. Then you can use an ancestor type, too.

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <CompositeCollection x:Key="CompositeCollection">
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={x:Reference stackPanel}, Path=DataContext.Movies}"/>
    </CompositeCollection>
</ListBox.Resources>
<ListBox.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CompositeCollection}}"/>
    </CompositeCollection>
</ListBox.ItemsSource>
```